# CodeIgniter not correctly performing a sql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In Ci I'm getting the following error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', '1f37540fc54292b018a9e993da38cb5647dc5587', NOW(), '0')' at line 1

INSERT INTO users (userpid, Email, Password, dateTimeRegistered, isLeader) VALUES ('147344f0e33367f9e6', erf', '1f37540fc54292b018a9e993da38cb5647dc5587', NOW(), '0')

Filename: C:\Workspace\htdocs\Misc-2\DruvlaCi-1\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

But everything seems to be right in the SQL query. Below is my query, any thoughts?

```
$query = $this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO users (userpid, Email, Password, dateTimeRegistered, isLeader) VALUES ('{$idgen}', {$postedEmail}', '{$hashedPass}', NOW(), '0')");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting the opening single quote for the email column

Try this instead

```
$query = $this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO users (userpid, Email, Password, dateTimeRegistered, isLeader) VALUES ('{$idgen}', '{$postedEmail}', '{$hashedPass}', NOW(), '0')");
```

Comment: Oh dang, I wasn't looking at anything past $idgen. lol thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, and please, use this syntax for inserting instead:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#insert

works so much safer.